# Как реализовать уведомления каждый час

Tags: android, checkbox, android-notification, flutter, dart

Долго вожусь с уведомлениями и никак не могу реализовать. В коде пытался, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку стартовала задержка в 10 секунд, а потом показывалось уведомление(у меня не работает). В идеале пытаюсь добавить checkbox, который при активном состоянии будет выводить уведомления автоматически каждый час.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:todo/main.dart';
import 'package:todo/theme.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



class ChangeTheme extends StatefulWidget{
  ChangeTheme({Key key, this.title}): super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  MyState createState() => new MyState();

}


class MyState extends State<ChangeTheme>{
  bool val = false;
  String message = "смена темы";
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

//  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
//    if (payload != null) {
//      print('notification payload: ' + payload);
//    }
//
//    await Navigator.push(
//      context,
//      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload)),
//    );
//  }
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TodoList()),
    );
//    debugPrint("payload : $payload");
//    showDialog(
//      context: context,
//      builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
//        title: new Text('Notification'),
//        content: new Text('$payload'),
//      ),
//    );
  }

//    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
//        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
//        payload: 'item x');

//    String trendingNewsId = '5';
//    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
//        0, 'Trending News', 'Donald trump says windmill cause cancer. ', platformChannelSpecifics,
//        payload: trendingNewsId);
//  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

 //   _getPrefs();


    return new Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Настройки'),
        ),
        body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         new Switch(
           value: val,
           onChanged: (bool e) => something(e),
          ),
          new Text (message),

          new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: lol,
            child: new Text(
              'Demo',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
            ),
          ),
        ],

      ),
      ),

//      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
//      //onPressed: _incrementCounter,
//      onPressed: _showNotification,
//    tooltip: 'Increment',
//    child: Icon(Icons.add),
//    ), // Thi
    );
  }

 void something(bool e) {
   ThemeChanger _themeChanger = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
   //_setPrefs();
    setState(() {

      if (e){
        _themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.dark());
        message = "Темнаяя тема";
        val = e;

      } else {
        _themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.light());
        message = "Светлая тема";
        val = e;

      }
    });

 }
//  showNotification() async {
//    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
//        'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
//        priority: Priority.High,importance: Importance.Max
//    );
//    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
//    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
//    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
//        0, 'Список задач', 'остались невыполненные задачи!', platform,
//        payload: 'Nitish Kumar Singh is part time Youtuber');
//  }
  lol() async {
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
    new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(seconds: 10));
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('your other channel id',
        'your other channel name', 'your other channel description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        scheduledNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);

  }
//  void _setPrefs() async {
//    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//    prefs.setBool('Switch', val);
//  }
//  void _getPrefs() async {
//    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//    if (prefs.getBool('Switch') != null)
//      val = prefs.getBool('Switch');
//  }





}
```

Comment: Проблема вопроса в том что:
1. Вы не даете полной информации по вопросу и коду (какой плагин использован, при каких условиях проблема воспроизводиться), из-за этого сложно понять с чем проблема.
2. Приложенный код не воспроизводим (нет значительных частей кода для запуска), из-за этого приходиться сначала разбираться как этот код должен запускаться, восстанавливая хронологию.
3. Код не читаемый и  содержит лишнюю воду (если вы задаете вопрос то приложите конкретный код для данного вопроса, уберите все лишнее, также можно добавить комментарии к некоторым участкам кода).

Comment: 4. Старайтесь придерживаться к code style языка, это необходимый аспект, так-как ваш код смотрят другие разработчики (Постарайтесь научиться правильно называть переменные, методы, классы). Данные проблемы относятся также и к предыдущему вопросу. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как правильно задавать вопросы?](https://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html)